# Grub2: "Invalid partition table!"

Tags: linux, boot, grub, bootloader, mbr

I have recently had to change bootloaded from my old `syslinux` to `GRUB2`. Since I have installed `GRUB2` bootloader I am getting the following message on every boot:

> Invalid partition table!

The message is displayed right after BIOS splash screen and before `GRUB2` menu loads. Text is in white font on black background, and with the exclamation mark in the end!

After the message is displayed, pressing any key results into `GRUB2` menu loading correctly and the rest of the boot process goes smoothly.

Before I used to hit power button on the machine and go make myself a cup of tea while it is booting. Now I have to wait for POST to finish and the error message to come up on the screen, then I have to hit any button on the keyboard, before the machine continues to boot. This is pretty annoying.

Is there any way to suppress this message or at least to make `GRUB2` automatically move to the next step?

Few more details:

- I have Windows XP and Linux Mint 17 on this machine (`NTFS` and `Ext3` respectively)
- `GRUB2` is installed on the USB stick, not on the main HDD of the machine. I use this USB as a "kickstarter" to start Linux. MBR of the main HDD is occupied by windoes boot loader
- Windows system partition is not starting on cylinder boundary, but I don't want to move it - too much risk
- With exactly the same setup `syslinux` used to boot without any error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read [this Arch Linux forum page](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=148467), you will find that several people have had the same issue you have. The consensus seems to be that GRUB2 has problems booting off a logical partition.

It is impossible however to make a precise recommendation in your case because you do not include enough info in your post. It would be helpful to have the output of *fdisk -l* for both HDD and USB stick, make and model of your BIOS, and confimation (I presume...) that you are using BIOS legacy mode, not UEFI boot. Also, it is not clear to me whether GRUB2 is complaining about an invalid partition table in the HDD or in the USB stick.

Comment: The problem was exactly as described: logical partition was marked as active/boot. Marking as solved.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same error upon install of Linux Mint.  I am not dual booting though.  The solution was to change boot mode from Legacy to UEFI in the BIOS.  Not sure if this solution is valid for people that are dual booting.

I realize this thread is a few years old, but I wanted to post this solution because I just ran into this issue in 2017.

Next time I install Linux the issue will probably happen again, and then I can search "invalid partition table" and find this post.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Invalid Partition Table!' message appeared after I made a new copy hard drive for a Dell laptop.  The message would clear after pressing a key, and the OS booted normally.

For Reference:

- PC - Dell Latitude E7240
- Partition type - MSDOS
- Partition - 1 ext4, Primary (/dev/sda1)
- BIOS - set to Legacy Boot
- OS - Mint 19.X

The solution that eliminated the nag message in my case:

- Gparted --> Manage Flags --> Enable/Checkbox the 'boot' flag.